# Ternary expression with a javascript object

Tags: javascript, ternary

Let's say I have the following javascript object:

```
var __error__ = {0: 'ok'}
```

I want to return an empty string if the key is not in the obj, and an error message otherwise. For example:

```
var value = __error__[col_num] ? "The value cannot be converted" : ""
```

How could this be done with a ternary expression properly? Do I need to do `__error__[col_num] == undefined` ? Or does the above expression evaluate to `false` by itself?

Comment: If the key doesn't exist, `__error__[col_num]` will evaluate to `undefined`. Because `undefined` is falsy, it will return `""`. The expression you have will work as you expect, assuming the value of said key won't be something like `null`, `undefined`, empty string, `0`. For that reason it may be best to strictly check existence as opposed to the implicit boolean that your approach uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check if they key exists in the object and not that the troothy of the value is `false` you should use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

```
var value = col_num in __error__ ? "The value cannot be converted" : ""
```

You can also use [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which returns true only if the object has that property (will return false if the property was inherited).

Here are a couple of examples to illustrate the differences

```js
var parent = {
  foo: undefined
};

var child = Object.create(parent);

console.log("foo" in parent); // parent has the "foo" property
console.log("foo" in child); // child has the "foo" property

console.log(parent.hasOwnProperty("foo")); // parent has the "foo" property
console.log(child.hasOwnProperty("foo")); // child has the "foo" property but it belonds to parent

console.log(child.foo !== undefined); // the foo property of child is undefined
console.log(!!child.foo); // the troothy of undefined is false

console.log(parent.foo !== undefined); // the foo property of parent is undefined
console.log(!!parent.foo); // the troothy of undefined is false
```

Comment: thanks, out of curiosity what's the difference between your approach and directly accessing the obj?

Comment: Using `in` returns true/false, whereas accessing the object will return undefined or the value at that key.

Comment: @user12282936 Your approach will evaluate to `false` in more instances than just "key doesn't exist"; it also includes cases where the key exists, but the value is something like `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, etc. Nick's answer will only evaluate to `false` if they key isn't found.

Comment: @user12282936 I've added some examples to make it easier to understand the usefulness of the `in` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property

```js
var __error__ = {
  0: 'ok'
}

var value = __error__.hasOwnProperty(1) ? "The value cannot be converted" : "Empty";
console.log(value)
```

Comment: @brik -- is that basically showing all built-ins of the object + any user-defined attributes that have been defined?